# Glassfish application displays blank screen when deployed with default web module

Tags: glassfish

I've had an issue with glassfish for years and figured it was time to see if anyone else ran into this issue.  All versions 3 and the latest 4.

I can deploy a web application (different instances on different servers/builds) with a default web module set with no issue.  The web application starts up and runs fine.

The problem I'm having is that once I have to restart the server, simply relaunching the web server only shows a blank white screen with no error and no information anywhere.  I have to then go into the admin console, undeploy the application, stop the glassfish server, redeploy, and then go back into the admin console and set the default web module.

If I do not set the default web module I do not run into these errors and I can stop/start/restart the server at will with no issues.  It's only when I designate a default web module that it shows the blank screen.  This is repeatable 100% for me.

Any ideas as to how to fix it?  It takes far too long to get the application back up and running when this happens.

Comment: Hi have been having the same issue too for way too long. I have to keep deploying undeploying changing the default web module etc until it finally works but sadly I don't know what fixes the issue. It just works after a lot of head scratching and hair pulling. Please let me know the exact steps you follow to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research here is what I have found out.
The blank page means that the contextroot defined during deployment gets overwritten by the default contextroot which glassfish gets from the name of the WAR file being deployed.

If deploying an application with the name `Application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` from as admin console or admin GUI and you either specify the `contextroot` as:-

1. `/application` in the `glassfish-web.xml` configuration file or
2. from the admin console `./asadmin deploy --contextroot application path-to/Application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`

The application with only be accessible from the browser by enter URL `<domain-name>/Application-1.0-SNAPSHOT` but what you want is your default web app to load when you access the domain name where it is deployed.

To achieve this you have to use the `--name` parameter to make sure that you the deployment name used matches the contextroot parameter value you want therefore

instead of:

from the admin console

`./asadmin deploy --contextroot application path-to/Application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`

you should do

`./asadmin --name application deploy --contextroot application path-to/Application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war`